# How do I refactor this fetch request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react.js, express.js, axios

I have this code that fetches data from a 3rd party api and sends it to my backend to be processed. The 3rd party api needs to target the user's localhost address so it has to come from the front end. I have the code below which works perfectly fine but it looks messy, I'm sure there is a better way to write it. Any suggestions?

I am using fetch for the original request because if I use axios to the 3rd party api I get a cors error.

```
  getLogs = () => {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/registerclient?name=${user.id}`)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((result) => {
        const regxml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(result);
        if (regxml.attributes.ResponseCode === "0") {
          axios.post(`/api/avaya/register/${user.id}`, regxml);
        }
        console.log(regxml);
      });

    fetch(`/api/avaya/getid/${user.id}`)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((result) => {
        fetch(
          `http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/nextnotification?clientid=${result}`
        )
          .then((res) => res.text())
          .then((result) => {
            const xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(result);
            axios.post(`/api/avaya/getlogs/${user.id}`, xml);
          });
      });
  };

  timer = (time) => {
    const date = new Date(time);
    return `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getLogs();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.getLogs, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

Comment: I think using async/await could improve the readability of your code. But I am not an expert on this topic. Actually I am learning it at the moment. Maybe you will find this video helpful: https://bit.ly/2V7hRZn

Comment: Other than you *think* it looks messy (an opinion) is there another issue and/or concern about the code? It's true that using async/await can reduce some of the "boiler-plate"y-ness of Promise-chains, I don't really see where that'd help you much. Only minor issue I see is that the second fetch's second fetch chain can be flattened down (i.e. un-nested). Perhaps factoring each fetch into smaller functions could help. TBH, the code appears fairly clean and readable to me.

Comment: The second `fetch` might be a good example of when to use `await` to get rid of the callback hell created by the nested `.then`

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Consider posting a new question instead, linking back to this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me share my `async await` solution for that:

- Because Your fetch function is pretty similar till the `res.text()`, I would create an own function (`fetchData` ) for that, what is returning a `Promise`, what is resolving a `res.text()`
- Now you can assign an `async` to your `getLogs`function
- Lets reorganise your code above
- **Error handling is missing here, but take care about it**

:

```
  fetchData = (url) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then(text => {
          res(text)
        })
        .catch(e => rej(e));
    });
  }

  getLogs = async () => {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    const regxmlPromise = fetchData(`http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/registerclient?name=${user.id}`);
    const secondDataPromise = fetchData(`/api/avaya/getid/${user.id}`);
   
    const resolves = await Promise.all([regxmlPromise, secondDataPromise]);
    
    const [firstResultStepOne, secondResultStepOne] = resolves || [];
    
    const secondResultStepTwo = await fetchData(`http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/nextnotification?clientid=${secondResultStepOne}`);

    if (firstResultStepOne) {
      const regxml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(firstResultStepOne);
      if (regxml.attributes.ResponseCode === "0") {
        axios.post(`/api/avaya/register/${user.id}`, regxml);
      }
      console.log(regxml);
    }
    
    if (secondResultStepTwo) {
      const xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(secondResultStepTwo);
      axios.post(`/api/avaya/getlogs/${user.id}`, xml);
    }
  };
```

Comment: This looks really good, i tried it in my code and works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: btw, is there a way to visualize in which order each steps happen? I assume the variable assignment first, then the if statement and then the promises resolve?

Comment: The code runs from the top to the buttom step by step. variable assignment first, promises resolve(because we are `await`ing it) and then the if statement

Comment: The if has to happen before the promises resolve because the firstResultStepOne will register the client which returns a client id. The secondResultStepTwo uses the client ID that was generated by firstResultStepOne and then posted to the user obj after the if statement checks firstResultStepOne to see if response is 0 meaning client is not already registered. secondResultStepOne will fetch the client id from the user doc in Mongodb and then it can be used in secondResultStepTwo. So my understanding here is that the If statement seem to run first, or am i understanding this wrong?

Comment: The if can not happen before the promises resolving, because we need the results from all `promises`. 
2 `promise`can fires in the same time, and `àwait`for both results here: `const resolves = await Promise.all([regxmlPromise, secondDataPromise]);`
This result will be an array with 2 element.(2x result from the backend).
We need to await them, because would reuse the data from the `secondResultStepOne ` in the `const secondResultStepTwo = await fetchData...`. After we having a result from the last promise (no errors), we can process the `firstResultStepOne ` and the `secondResultStepTwo`.

Comment: Ok i console.logged the steps to find out what is happening. It is working in the order you say it does. The  secondResultStepTwo runs before the if statements and returns a response code 2 which means the client is not registered as it's trying to use the old client id that it fetched in secondResultStepOne. Then the if statement runs, uploads the new client id, and the whole thing runs again as it's on a setinterval loop and this time secondResultStepTwo returns the correct value as it is now using the new client id.